# Webpack Won't Bundle CSS with ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: css, webpack, bundle, extract-text-plugin

I know someone is going to mark this as a duplicate, *but nothing on the entire web seems to be what I need.*

[image: Screenshot of webpack config and directory structure]

This is almost a direct copy/paste of the example found [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#styles-from-initial-chunks-into-separate-css-output-file). This is after meticulously following along with the tutorial found [here](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/webpack-fundamentals/table-of-contents).

When I run `webpack` from the command line, I get the `./bundle/app.js` output, but there's nothing relating to CSS anywhere.

**It simply won't bundle the CSS, as far as I can tell**. What in [Laniakea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laniakea_Supercluster) could be the issue???

Deeply Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the 'style-loader' prefix now, it should just be

```
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!less-loader") etc
```